# Generate realizations of X random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $X,Z,U$ be a random variables where $X= \frac{Z}{U}$ , $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $U \sim U(0,1)$.
Let $Z,U$ be indenpendent.

The task is to generate realizations of X.
Is it okay to take a realization of $Z$ and divided by one from $U$?
Should I obtained the distribution of X first?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $N(0,1),U(0,1)$ denotes normal and uniform standard distribution.

Comment: Since $Z$ and $U$ are independent, yes your approach will work fine.

Comment: Well, maybe not quite so 'fine'. Be careful. Your denominators will often be very near $0,$ so $X$ will be heavy tailed. Maybe ponder Cauchy distribution $\equiv$ Student's t with DF=1.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation in R: For clarity of plotting, truncated
simulated values to $(-20,20).$ Boost Cauchy density
by constant $c$ to account for omitted observations.
The median of this Cauchy distribution is 0. Its mean does not exist.

The summary below is for all 100,000 values generated.

```
set.seed(2020)  # for reproducibility 
u = rnorm(10^5); z = rnorm(10^5)
x1=z/u; x = x1[abs(x)<20]
summary(x1)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-606391.4      -1.0       0.0      -8.9       1.0  180980.7 

c = 10^5/length(x);  c
[1] 1.033891
hist(x, prob=T, br=70, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.35))
 curve(c*dt(x,1), add=T, col="red", n=10001)
```

[image]